# Varnish doesn't cache first hit at all, only second hit

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

I have Varnish 4 with Drupal 7. In Drupal `settings.php` I have:

```
// Tell Drupal it's behind a proxy.
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;

// Tell Drupal what addresses the proxy server(s) use.
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');

// Bypass Drupal bootstrap for anonymous users so that 
// Drupal sets max-age &lt; 0.
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;

// Make sure that page cache is enabled.
$conf['cache'] = 1;
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 0;
// Set page cache max-age to 600 secs (10 min) 
// Change this to the highest time possible for your needs
// Drupal will set a Cache-Control: "max-age=600" header 
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 21600;

$conf['cache_backends'] = array('sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.cache.inc');

$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
```

In the varnish vcl file I have:

```
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

 ## ADMIN PAGES ##

    # Here we filter out all URLs containing Drupal administrative sections
    if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/update\.php$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/admin$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/user$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/user/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$") {
           return (pass);
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
if (bereq.url ~ "(?i)\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
# Set cached objects to expire after 1 hour instead of the default 120 seconds.
    set beresp.ttl = 4h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
if (obj.hits > 0) {
               set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        } else {
               set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }
}
```

This is my header at isvarnishworking:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 13:51:24 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dfac4e840061f192552b77dfd3430fcfc1519998683; expires=Sat, 02-Mar-19 13:51:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.mydomain.net; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.4.45
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires:    Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  max-age=64800, public
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language:   en
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator:    Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Vary:   Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Varnish:  459087
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache:    MISS
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 3f54567d343346ec-EWR
Content-Encoding:   gzip
```

I'm using Cloudflare, but I've already been try to shutdown Cloudflare for 2-3 days. Still, Varnish doesn't hit the first time, only the second time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a normal behaviour :

- first url hit : Varnish puts the page in cache with some id
- only following hits will serve the *cached id* instead of querying the backend.

If you want anonymous users to be always served by varnish, you need to implement a **[cache warmer](https://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl%20-A%20%27Cache%20Warmer%27%20-s%20-L%20%20%24line%20%3E%20%2Fdev%2Fnull%202%3E%261)** logic.

Setup a sitemap. Then create a cron task that will parse the sitemap with `curl` for instance,  and run that cron task at a frequency synced with your cache expiry time...

Comment: Was about to say this. It sounds like there is no record for it, so the second request is the one coming from cache.